# Is there any way to apply conditional logic for keeping/dropping columns in SAS?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to drop particular columns in SAS based on a macro variable, my hands are slightly tied in terms of what code I can use - so I need a solution in BASE SAS.

I've already tried wrapping the drop/keep in an if, but I know the drop happens at run time so this won't work.

Example:

```
data dropsomecolumns;

  if &somemacro =1 then do;
    drop somecol1 somecol2;
  end;

run;
```

Comment: Are the columns known ahead of time? So, in your example, is it always going to be somecol1 and somecol2?

Comment: Yeah, they'll always be known in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to use macro code to conditionally generate the code you want.

```
data dropsomecolumns;
  set have;
%if &somemacro =1 %then %do;
  drop somecol1 somecol2;
%end;
run;
```

Or change so that the macro variable has the list of columns to drop.

```
%let drop_columns=somecol1 somecol2;
data dropsomecolumns(drop=&drop_columns);
  set have;
run;
```

Note that the drop statement will give a warning if no variables are listed, but the drop= dataset option will not give that warning.

Answer (score 0):

You have have no variables listed and it will work fine and assumes not are to be dropped. So if the macro variable is a list of variables just use:

```
 drop &drop_columns;
```

This works fine:

```
data demo;
    set sashelp.class;
    drop ;
run;
```

So no conditional logic needed.